# How to lookup scores in 3x3 matrix given a row and column value

Tags: r

I have a matrix I want to extract values from.

```
 scoring.matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -2   -1    0
[2,]   -1    0    1
[3,]    0    1    2
```

Each person has two numeric variables (intercept and slope), which are converted to categorical variables based on the quartile the values are in: first quartile: 1, 2nd or 3rd quartile: 2, top quartile: 3. So, a hypothetical person scores in the top quartile on the first variable and in the middle 50% on the second variable, I will select the value in the 3rd row, and 2nd column, which is 1. Here is the R code with which I attempt to do this:

```
resfil2 <- resfil %>%
        mutate(level.cats=as.numeric(cut(intrcpt.est, c(-Inf, int.qcuts, Inf), levels=1:3, labels=c("Bottom Quartile", "Middle 50%", "Top Quartile"))),
               slope.cats=as.numeric(cut(slope.est, c(-Inf, sl.qcuts, Inf), levels=1:3, labels=c("Bottom Quartile", "Middle 50%", "Top Quartile"))),
               score=scoring.matrix[level.cats, slope.cats])
```

`int.qcuts` and `sl.qcuts` are the values corresponding to the 25th and 75th percentiles; `intrcpt.est` and `slope.est` are the original numeric variables I convert to categoricals (which are then converted to integers, 1:3).
Instead of getting one "score" variable per person, I get 43 score variables (score.1, score.2, ..., score.43). (There are 43 rows in the original data frame.)

Any idea on how to fix this?

**EDIT**
I've simplified this as much as I can. Here is part of the data frame:

```
   network_id level.cats slope.cats
1           1          3          2
2           2          3          1
3           3          3          3
4           4          3          2
5           5          1          2
6           6          3          3
7           7          3          2
8           8          2          3
9           9          1          1
10         10          2          3
```

The scoring matrix is as above, but I converted it to a data frame, thinking it would be less complicated. I can get the result for the first row by hand:

```
> scoring.df[3,2]
[1] 1
```

But when I try to do it for all 43 rows in the data frame like this:

```
    resfil3 <- resfil2 %>%
        mutate(score=unlist(scoring.df[level.cats, slope.cats]))
```

I get this error message:

```
mutate(score=unlist(scoring.df[level.cats, slope.cats]))
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `score = unlist(scoring.df[level.cats, slope.cats])`.
Caused by error:
! `score` must be size 43 or 1, not 1849.
```

As before, it's trying to make a 43x43 data frame; it looks like it's trying to do a crossing -- don't know why. Here is the results of `last_trace()` if it make sense to anyone. (It doesn't to me.)

```
 1. ├─resfil2 %>% ...
 2. ├─dplyr::mutate(., score = unlist(scoring.df[level.cats, slope.cats]))
 3. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(., score = unlist(scoring.df[level.cats, slope.cats]))
 4. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```r
cats <- mapply(\(d, q) as.numeric(cut(d, c(-Inf, q, Inf))), 
               resfil, list(int.qcuts, sl.qcuts))
scoring.matrix[cats]
# [1]   1  0  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  0  2  0  0 -1  0 -1  1 -1  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  0 -1  1  2
# [28]  0 -2  0  1  0  0  0  0  1 -1  0  1  0  1  0  0 -1 -2 -1 -2  1  0 -1  1 -1  1  1
# [55]  0  0  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  1  1  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  1  0  0  0  0  1 -1  0  0 -2  0
# [82]  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1 -1  1  0  0
```

`mapply` successively applies given function to the elements of further arguments, so the code above basically does this:

```r
cut_q <- function(d, q) as.numeric(cut(d, c(-Inf, q, Inf)))
cats <- cbind(
  cut_q(resfil[[1]], int.qcuts),
  cut_q(resfil[[2]], sl.qcuts)
)
```

Data (*Next time please include them in your question!*):

```r
scoring.matrix <- matrix(c(-2, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2), 3)
set.seed(0)
resfil <- data.frame(
  intrcpt.est=rnorm(100),
  slope.est=rnorm(100)
)
int.qcuts <- sl.qcuts <- c(-1, 1)
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, but I'm afraid I don't understand it.

Comment: @Stuart I added an explanation of what `mapply` does in my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I don't know why I was so fixated on extracting the numbers from a 2-dimensional matrix, but I was able to solve the problem by going at it a slightly different way. It's way easier to convert the `scoring.matrix` to a 1-dimensional vector, and then calculate the single index to the scoring data in a vector:

```
resfil3 <- resfil2 %>%
     mutate(v.index=(level.cats - 1) * 3 + slope.cats,
            score=scoring.matrix[v.index])
```

Ah, actually, the matrix does not even need to be converted to a vector. Easier is better.